# Origin of "desktop capture engine"

Tags: software, video-recording, capturing

I'm trying to locate a desktop capture driver.

I am using Flash Media Encoder 3.2 and had a device listed as "`desktop capture engine`" in my list of devices. Allowed me to stream my desktop.

I had no idea where it came from so I tried to uninstall some programs to see which one "removed" it. Bright idea, I Know!

So after removing RealVNC and Super! from my computer, it's gone, but re-installing those programs doesn't re-add the device. I'm wondering if I had a different version of RealVNC installed. I don't remember downloading from their website before.

Anyone know what the origin of this driver might be?

Comment: super now have more virus/spiwares and trash, uninstall it.. if can the damage in the windows is terrible..
i lost more time romoving, it from windows init, services, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed SUPER today, and Desktop Capture Engine has appeared on my computer.

Comment: I have just installed this thing and after I declined all the "useless ads" I got like over 9000 viruses with this app. I am already dealing with them for an hour and actually winning. But gosh... Like really? This type of program makes this to my computer?